# Add pre-release version format to Go versioning validator script

Tags: regex, go, semantic-versioning

I am trying to modify an already existing code for a simple versioning check script that has been written in Go. The script is for checking if a version tag update is in line with the expectations and allows only specific format through.
So far it only accepts versions in this format:

"vX.X.X"

The Go code for this is as below:

Pattern = `^v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+$`

By this, pre-release tags are excluded, which means a problem for us.
Code should allow both:

v1.2.3
v1.2.4

and

v1.2.3-test
v1.2.4-beta

versions. How do I add this? Would this be the correct pattern?

Pattern = `^v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+$` + `^v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+-[$]`

Please advise if possible, I am really not experienced with Go.

Comment: What happens when you try your suggested pattern? Does it work? If so, it's probably correct. If not, what problems do you encounter? Be specific.

Answer (score 1):

[Semver.org](https://semver.org/) has [published correct and tested regexes](https://semver.org/#is-there-a-suggested-regular-expression-regex-to-check-a-semver-string).

They even post regex101 links that include the test data:

- [PCRE with named capture groups](https://regex101.com/r/Ly7O1x/3/)
- [PCRE + others with numbered capture groups](https://regex101.com/r/vkijKf/1/)

None of the posted regexes, so far in this thread are correct. They are far too simple to cover all of the nuances of SemVer syntax.

---

Please always refer SemVer regex related questions to the SemVer FAQ referenced above, it will always point to the most up to date regexes. I did a search on GiHub about five or six years ago, and found several hundred incorrect regexes purported to be useful. You'll find some relevant discussions on this topic at [SemVer Issues](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues?q=is%3Aissue+regex).  See [this longish thread](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/232), its related links and [this PR](https://github.com/semver/semver/pull/460) for the full history of the development of the regexes in the FAQ.

Even with a handful of experienced coders working the SemVer regex problem over the course of several years, we still missed a couple things:

- https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/826
- https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/788

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Pattern = `^v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)?$`

Here is a sample snippet that will print the unmatched tags from a list of tags.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    pattern := `^v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)?$`

    tests := []string{
        "v1.2", // this will not match with the pattern

        "v1.2.3",
        "v1.2.3-test",
        "v1.2.3-test-beta", // this will not match with the pattern

        "v1.2.4-beta",
        "v1.2.4-beta12", // this will not match with the pattern
    }

    reg := regexp.MustCompile(pattern)

    for _, test := range tests {
        if !(reg.MatchString(test)) {
            fmt.Printf("[%v] - not matching \n", test)
        }
    }
}
```

See [How to write regular expressions?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-regular-expressions/) to learn more about Regular Expressions.

Comment: I like the link to [How to write regular expressions?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-regular-expressions/) Especially the part about "The Escape Symbol" (hint, something with a dot)

Comment: This is wrong for too many reasons to go into here.  Grab the test data from https://regex101.com/r/vkijKf/1/ and try it against your regex.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Code should allow both ... How do I add this?"*

You can create a new group, matching the hyphen and any subsequent characters.
And, apply the *?* quantifier after it, to allow for, zero or one occurence.

Note, this a *non-capturing* group, which has the syntax of, `(?:)`.

```
^v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(?:-.+)?$
```

As a note, you can use *\d* to match *[0-9]*.

```
^v\d+.\d+.\d+(?:-.+)?$
```

And, it is worth mentioning that the dot, ., is a meta-character, so typically you'll want to *un-escape* it's value by preceding it with a reverse-solidus character, *\*.
In this case, since you are matching a single character, it is somewhat irrelevant.

```
^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:-.+)?$
```

Comment: These are not SemVer compliant. They do not capture all the nuances of valid SemVer version strings.

Comment: @jwdonahue, what would need to be done, to create compliance?

Comment: See the [SemVer FAQ's](https://semver.org/#is-there-a-suggested-regular-expression-regex-to-check-a-semver-string) referenced in my answer.

Comment: @jwdonahue, lol, if you wrote an answer, then why are you commenting for me to change mine?

Comment: But you would have to add the 'v', since the OP is processing tags and those generally have the non-compliant 'v' prefix.

Comment: I am not suggesting you should change it, I am simply pointing out that it is wrong in an attempt to limit the propagation of non-complaint regexes claiming to handle SemVer strings (I have encountered hundreds). It's up to you whether you improve your answer, delete it, or ignore me.

Comment: @jwdonahue, so if you've written an answer, why would you not just apply the solution?

Comment: As stated earlier, refer to [this SemVer FAQ](https://semver.org/#is-there-a-suggested-regular-expression-regex-to-check-a-semver-string). The correct answer often involves posting links to relevant information, rather than posting code.

Comment: @jwdonahue, exactly; just apply the solution. _"... How do I add this? Would this be the correct pattern? ..."_